# Arithmetic mean greater than equal to Geometric mean condition

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

Let's say there are two numbers a and b:

In all the books it is said that the arithmetic mean of a and b is greater than or equal to the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ if $a>0, b>0$.

But why can't we say the arithmetic mean of a and b is greater than or equal to the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ if $a>=0, b>=0$?

Comment: Do you know that the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"? Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

> But why can't we say the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$ is greater than or equal to the geometric mean of $a$ and $b$ if $a\ge 0,\,b\ge 0$?

Well we can say that too, since it's true. For if $a\ge 0,\,b\ge 0,$ then we may write $a=x^2,\,b=y^2.$ Now since $(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\ge 0,$ or that $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy,$ it follows that $$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\ge xy,$$ or in other terms, that $$\frac{a+b}{2}\ge \sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab},$$ provided we choose $x,y\ge 0,$ which we do.

Comment: Nice, but you left a square.

Comment: @yngabl Which do you mean?

Comment: (x-y)=x^2+y^2-2xy

Comment: @yngabl Oh, I see. That's a typo. Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

$a=0$ or $b=0$ is a trivial condition for the AM-GM inequality as if any one of them is 0, GM becomes 0 and AM will obviously be greater than 0. $a=b=0$ is the equality condition for the equality. Hence the books display it as $a{\gt}0$ and $b{\gt}0$ as the non trivial condition.

Comment: if its a trivial condition why we can't say AM>=GM if a>=0 and b>=0 officially.

Comment: This is because the inequality in its full form is $AM{\ge}GM{\ge}HM$ and if a term was 0, it would mess up the HM as ${1\over 0}$ is undefined

Comment: I am not talking about HM here , only AM>=GM

Comment: In books, all three are represented in one inequality.

Comment: what I think of is this, but I am not sure if this is the reason, if a=0 and b=0, then if we calculate GM, then it would be zero. It is also true that a,GM,b will be in GP by definition of geometric mean so common ratio will be 0/0 which is undefined. I am just guessing, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0$ be two reals.

we can write
$$a=(\sqrt{a})^2 \text{ and } \; b=(\sqrt{b})^2$$

thus

$$a+b-2\sqrt{ab}=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\ge 0$$
and

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

In the case $a>b\ge 0$, we have
$$\frac{a+b}{2} > \sqrt{ab}$$

Comment: yes its correct so for a>=0 and b>=0 also AM>=GM , so why books say only for a>0 and b>0

Comment: @user3290550 Not the books but those who wrote.

Comment: yeah, so people who wrote would have written because of some reason right, why would anybody constraint the condition to be a>0 and b>0 if a>=0 and b>=0 also looks fine

Comment: If $a=0$ or $b=0$ it is obvious.

Comment: who said there is no need to mention the obvious things. If in some question 1/x is given, it is always mentioned that x can not be zero, so whats your take on this. Why they need to mention it, it is well obvious.

Comment: @user3290550 Ok you are right . Good night.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that we can't say it?

We can say it. The inequality

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt{ab}$$

is true for all $a \geq 0, b \geq 0$

There we go. We said it and it's a valid statement.

Side note: maybe it was enough for the purpose of the book/chapter/whatever to claim the statement is true just for positive $a$ and $b$. In general... if you meet some statement A in a book, it does not mean there isn't a more general version B of this statement that is also true.